# Rotated Vertical Button not Aligning With Parent Left

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button which is rotated at -90. Rotated button is not align left with parent.

Folowing is the XML

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_showChapters"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_show"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:rotation="-90"
            android:text=" Show Chapters " />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

following is the output.
[image]

But I want to stick this button left with paren.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I would like to drop an answer here for future references.

I had exactly the same problem with the exception that I wanted to align my button to the right of its parent. The problem here is that when rotating a view, the pivot is chosen as its center, unless stated otherwise (I don't know how to do that). I couldn't find any attributes to do the job for me; so I implemented the following method:

```
private void transformShowPopupButton() {
    int w = btn_showPopup.getWidth(), h = btn_showPopup.getHeight();
    int diff = w/2-h/2;
    btn_showPopup.setRotation(270);
    btn_showPopup.setTranslationX(diff);
}
```

Basically, this method moves the button until it aligns with its parent. The amount of the movement equals the difference between `getWidth()/2` and `getHeight()/2` (of course I didn't have any margin and I had the button aligned with its parent. If you specified a margin value, you need to add that up, as well.)

To align the button to the left of its parent, you need to translate it by `-diff`.

**Important:** To be able to get height and width of a view, `btn_showPopup` in my case, calling `transformShowPopupButton()` inside `onCreate()` won't work. So calling it inside `onWindowFocusChanged()` does the trick.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    transformShowPopupButton();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` for a `Button` in `RelativeLayout`. Change it as

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Then the button will be aligned left of the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Have u removed `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` or changed `android:layout_centerVertical="false"`

Comment: @AhmedNawaz where you have removed. Remove in both `RelativeLayout` and `Button`. Please let me know if u cant resolve the issue

Comment: I have tried many things like this. Problem is due to rotation. Button getting space accroding to before rotation.

Comment: Have u placed `android:configChanges="orientation"` for an Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file??

Comment: Yes I have placed `android:configChanges="orientation"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.